# How to validate empty input boxes from a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to validate every single item in my form so in case one is empty I would like to print an alert. 
So for that I'm using the `form.serializeArray()` to check for any input box that could be empty. but my code is not working. Am I doing it good?

Here's my [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/vqr22ebz/3/)

Comment: If you are interested I found [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) to be an incredibly simple and effective validation library built on jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `var form = page.find(..);`
use `var form = $(..);`

modified.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vqr22ebz/6/

But there is another problem, you are calling the alert for every empty field.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `page.find()` instead of `$('')` for selecting your form.

#### Suggestion 1 :

To improve your code and don't repeat code uselessly you can change your code like that :

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    var formItems = $(this).serializeArray();

    formItems.forEach(function (i, v) {
      if (v.value == '' || v.value == null || typeof v.value == 'undefined') {
         window.alert("need to fill up all those fields");
      }
    });
});
```

#### Suggestion 2 :

To not make too many pop-up; you can specify the field who is empty.

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    var formItems = $(this).serializeArray();

    formItems.forEach(function (i, v) {
      if (v.value == '' || v.value == null || typeof v.value == 'undefined') {
         $('input[name="' + v.name + '"]').val("This field must not be empty");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.find()` method searches for a specified text in the document and highlights the matches.

You can further simplify your code:

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( form ) {
    $(this).serializeArray().forEach(function (i, v) {
      if (v.value == '' || v.value == null || typeof v.value == 'undefined') {
        alert("need to fill up all those fields");
      }
    });
});
```